# unable to upload files using FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ftp-client

i trying to upload pdf file to my websites Uploads folder but throwing below error.

My code is----

```
      try
         {
            string ftp = "ftp://ftp.MYSITE.com/Uploads/";
            byte[] fileBytes = null;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp +   fileName);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.AppendFile;
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("H:\\files\\User_Manual.pdf");
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("Append status: {0}", response.StatusDescription);
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            String status = ((FtpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusDescription;
        }


**line " Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();" throwing error.**
```

Error is------------

The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

Please help.

**Update.**

Below is the complete solution for the same.

http://complexquery.blogspot.in/2015/09/upload-file-using-ftp.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like permission issue. Instead of full path, use relative path..

Answer (score 0):

First check to see if the folder exists {550 Permission Denied (or No such file or folder)} Then check folder permissions to see if you actually have write permissions on that folder.

Comment: remember just because you can write via filezilla doesn't mean IIS has access to the folder as well. To test give all the file access to "Everyone"